# Is there any way to ignore dark mode in my app xamarin forms (android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

To ignore the dark mode the only thing I am using is

```
    AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

But it does not work well for me since when navigating to a WebView and returning the entries that I do not have configured with white backgroundcolor they turn black.

entry when entering the app -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10izW.png)

[image]

After navigating a web view and return -> [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZz3t.png)

[image]

The instantiation of the entry

```
 var lastNameEntry = new Entry
            {
                Placeholder = "Apellido",
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                ReturnType = ReturnType.Next,
            };
```

The solution I have is to put BackGroundColor = Color.White in all the entries but is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Create a `Style` with TargetType `Entry`, in your `App.xaml` "Resources" dictionary. Set desired properties there. NOTE: Where is that `DefaultNightMode` line? If it is in `All.xaml.cs` / `OnResume`, it should be applied when it returns to your app. [Other suggestions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64183173/199364).

Comment: I solved it by placing
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
in method OnResume()
I'm doing fine but will this be okay?

Comment: Could you provide the code for me to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 2):

i was having the same problem. I solved the problem as described below.

1. Modify the styles.xml file:

   ```
    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
   ```
2. Modify the mainactivity.cs file:

   Theme = "@style/MainTheme" to Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Base"
3. OnCreate method starts like this

   ```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo; 
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ```

Comment: I tried many solutions found on the internet, this one is the first that also worked on my redmi pro